# Is QGIS unable to modify layers from a .gdb?

Tags: field-calculator, attribute-table, qgis-2.4

There is a .gdb file with several census tables I downloaded from TIGER. I am trying to join one of the tables to a shapefile but am not able to as the join field for the table contains excess characters. When I go into the field calculator to make a new attribute field without those characters, I found I was not able to and was greeted with: "This layer does not support adding new provider fields."

Is it possible to somehow edit this attribute field in QGIS or will I need to use ArcGIS for it?

Comment: Do you have this read/write driver http://www.gdal.org/drv_filegdb.html or this read-only one http://www.gdal.org/drv_openfilegdb.html?

Comment: It seems I only have the openfilegdb driver. I am assuming that if I look into installing the other driver you linked then it will work around the issue? Thank you so much!